# Find the result of T given matrices against ordered basises

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transition-matrix, stochastic-matrices

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the ordered basis $v_1 = (1, 3)$, $v_2 = (2, 5)$.
> Let $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear image with as the matrix with respect to $v_1, v_2$:
>
> $A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$
>
> After calculation we find the following matrix of T with respect to the standard basis:
>
> $B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 4 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$
>
> Find $T((3, 8))$ using the matrix $B$
>
> Then find $T((3, 8))$ using $A$

What I can't figure out is how you can correctly determine $T((3, 8))$ using $A$.

.

(Apologies for any errors, this is translated from a non-english textbook without the solution to this problem)

It is my understanding that any matrix $C$ of $T$ with respect to standard basises (bases?) is simply equal to the matrix you would use to represent the linear image $T$ to begin with, $T_C = T$.

So therefore, since $B$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis, $T_B = T$ and we get $T_B((3,8)) = T((3, 8)) = (11, 28)$

I thought I could use this:
If $ \mathcal{B} = v_1, v_2 $ and $ \mathcal{B}' = e_1, e_2 $ the standard basis, then the relationship between the matrices and the basises is given by the schema:

$
\begin{matrix}
 &  & A = m(T)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}} &  &  \\
 & \mathcal{B} & \longrightarrow  & \mathcal{B} &  \\
m(I)_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} & \uparrow  &  & \downarrow  & m(I)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'} \\
 & \mathcal{B}' & \longrightarrow & \mathcal{B}' &  \\
 &  & B = m(T)_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'} &  & 
\end{matrix}
$

So $
B = m(T)_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}'} = m(I)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'} m(T)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}} m(I)_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} = m(I)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'} A m(I)_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}
$

So I could figure out the solution to $T((3,1))$ "using $A$" by going through essentially translating the problem into $A$, and then back to $B$. I think that this way I would never be using the solution they've given for $B$ directly in my solution "using $A$".

I then determine $m(I)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'}$ first, since it's easy to determine the coordinates with respect to the standard basis, they're just equal to $v_1, v_2$. I get

$ 
m(I)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$

And then I determine $ m(I)_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}} = (m(I)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'})^{-1}  
= \begin{bmatrix}
-5 & 2 \\
3 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$

And now it would have to be true that
$
B = m(I)_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{B}'} A m(I)_{\mathcal{B}'}^{\mathcal{B}}
$

I get:

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 4 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-5 & 2 \\3 & -1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}5 & -1 \\12 & -2\end{bmatrix}$

But it isn't, so I must've done something wrong.
But I cannot figure out what this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that I can think of that you can solve the question.

$1$. Simply reconstruct $T$ using the columns of the matrix. Consider the following example on how to do that.

Example: Consider the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4\\ 3 & 6\end{bmatrix}$. Let's assume that this matrix is the matrix of a linear map $T$ with respect to the standard basis of $R^2$. Then by definition of the matrix of a linear map, we know that $T(1, 0)=(1, 3)$ and $T(0, 1)=(4, 6)$. Thus, $T(x, y)=T(x(1, 0)+y(0, 1))=(x,3x)+(4y,6y)=(x+4y,3x+6y)$. Thus, the linear map this matrix represents is defined by $T(x, y)=(x+4y, 3x+6y)$. You can simply evaluate any vector using this. Recall that a linear map is completely determined on it's basis.

$2$. Let $M(T)$ denote the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis. Then, the matrix of a vector $v\in V$ is defined to be the $n\times 1$ matrix whose columns contain the scalars needed to write $v$ as a linear combination of the basis of your choice. For example, consider the vector $(2, 8)\in R^2$. let's pick the basis to be $(1, 0), (0, 1)$. Then the matrix of the vector $(2, 8)$ denoted $M(2, 8)=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 8\end{bmatrix}$ as the scalars needed to write $(2, 8)$ with respect to the standard basis are $2$ and $8$ as $(2, 8)=2(1, 0)+8(0, 1)$.

Then find the matrix of $(3, 8)$ with respect to the basis for $A$ and the basis of $B$. Then use the following result to get an answer.

Theorem: Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis of $V$. Let $T\in L(V, W)$ and $v\in V$. Then we have that $M(Tv)=M(T)M(V)$. Where $M(T)$ denotes the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and $M(v)$ denotes the matrix of $v$ with respect to the basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Where of course $M(Tv)$ is computed with respect to the basis of $W$.

Example: Define a linear map $T:R^2\to R^2$ by $T(x, y)=(2x, 2y)$. Then the matrix of this linear map with respect to the standard basis is $M(T)=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$. The above result tells me that for the vector $(3, 4)\in R^2$, I should have that $M(Tv)=M(T)M(v)$. In other word, $M(6, 8)=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 8\end{bmatrix}$.

This was all done with respect to the standard basis. For a different basis, you should be able to change the results.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think your first approach is what I used in the first part of that question to find the result using their given matrix $B$ with respect to the standard basis. For the second approach, I'm not entirely sure I follow all the operations you used in the theorem,  what would $L(V, W)$ represent? I'm assuming we have $T: V \to W$ the linear image. I *think* your example is the strategy I used in my attempt to get my answer "using $A$". Any chance you could further clarify?

Comment: @fatCat9999 Yeah sure. $L(V,W)$ denotes the set of all linear maps $T$ from $V$ to $W$. Was there anything else that was confusing. I agree there is a lot to take in in that paragraph. Feel free to ask!

Comment: actually, could you potentially double-check the comment of Andijvie on this post too? Because in that case I think your definition is just a different way to word/write one that I've read in my textbook (and that one I essentially tried to apply in my solution here).

Comment: @fatCat9999 Yeah I think Andijvie is correct that the matrix is not right. As for the answer, you should be able to find $T((3,8))$ using the theorem I quoted in my answer. Then for second part, calculate how you can write $(3,8)$ as a linear combination of $(1,3), (2,5)$. Put those scalars in a matrix and multiply that matrix by the matrix Andigvie has given you. You should get your answer!

Comment: Thanks @Seeker!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is an error in the question. If $B$ is the matrix of the transformation $T$ with respect to the standard basis, then the matrix with respect to the ordered basis $(v_{1},v_{2})$ should be $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\2&3\end{bmatrix}$, not $\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Indeed, $T(v_{1})=Bv_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}4\\10\end{bmatrix}=0\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}+2\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\end{bmatrix}$, so $A\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ must be $\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: The definition that the matrix with respect to the ordered basis is just equal to the matrix with which you could otherwise represent T is a definition that is given in my text book, too. So I think you must be right if A and B are meant to refer to the same matrix (which the text in the original language seems to indicate). It's really unfortunate to work on problems that have no solution key like this, I got stuck on this for many hours under the assumption that A and B relate to the same T and the question itself must be correct :-(.

Comment: That is indeed very unfortunate. For an author, these kinds of errors are easy to make, but students can lose a lot of time to them. If you can contact the author, you may consider doing so.

As an aside, in order for $A$ and $B$ to represent the same transformation $T$, they must have the same eigenvalues. As this is not the case here, the question as stated must be wrong.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that fact! I'll be contacting the authors of this book in this case so that they may clarify it for other students. The next chapter talks in depth on eigenvalues, so I did not know to use that yet, but good to know that they can be used in this way!